# how to write language ID to registry in Installshield 2018?

Tags: installshield-2018

I need to read language code from InstallShield and do customized actions in another application with language code selected from run time dialog box.

I have tried to write language code variable in Instalshield registry with variable SELECTED_LANGUAGE. But I don't see any code in registry when i checked after MSI installation.I tried in environment variable as well with same variable SELECTED_LANGUAGE.

I see SELECTED_LANGUAGE instead of language code which is selected from run time language dialog box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create registry key with data [ProductLanguage]. you will get product language code as Identifier (Windows Installer–Based Projects and Suite/Advanced UI Projects).
Refer Identifiers in following path: https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/IHelpGlobLangIdentifiers.htm